# Should I feel the seams of 9mm underlay foam on a swimming pool below the new liner?

Tags: pool, foam

I have just had my liner changed with all the installer recommendations. The day after the pool was filled, I noticed that were the underlay has been taped together is visible and there is a noticeable groove where the sediment from the tap water is collecting.
I think that this is not OK and that something else should have been done. The installer says that the job is correct and that there is nothing else they could have done better. Does anyone have experience with this issue? Under the foam, there is a base of sand.

Comment: Pictures are always nice.

Comment: What kind of pool are we talking about? Please revise to give more detail.

Comment: There's a lot of pressure on the liner. It will tend to confirm to the shape of whatever is supporting it. That isn't necessarily a problem...

Comment: @keshlam   It might reduce the lifespan of the liner from rubbing/pinching if the seams under it are not holding it up.

Comment: It is a half in half out pool with metal walls, unfortunately the lines are not visible on camera so no photo uploaded. I would say that what I can feel between the joints is at least 5mm